VBA error 3464 on one laptop but not the other
I have a small Access DB that only I use. I wrote a little custom code that does what I need it to do.
I am no coding expert, so I am sure the code I wrote is not the way someone who knows what they are doing would. But it works for me, except on a certain specific laptop.
If I put this.accdb file on a thumb drive and open directly from the thumb drive, on one laptop, it works without issue. On another one, I get:

Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression

The code is below and I cannot figure out why it works on one machine but not another. While advice on how to write the code better is helpful, right now I am only interested in getting past the error.
The code is meant to query an ID number and then go to that record on a form.
Again, it works without issue on one computer. On another I get the error. I'm using the same exact file off the same thumb drive. I have ruled the thumb drive out as the cause, as the same thing happens when opening the file off the hard drives of each laptop. The MS Access versions are the same on both laptops: Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2410 Build 16.0.18129.20100) 64-bit
Code:
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)    
Dim WID As Integer
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset  
Dim strSQL As String  
Dim curday As Date  
strSQL = "SELECT tblWeeks.ID FROM tblWeeks WHERE (((DateValue(Now())) Between [Weekstartdate] And [weekenddate]));"  
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)  
WeekIDSQL = rst!ID  
cmbWeekSelector = WeekIDSQL  
DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "frmTimesheet", acFirst, "[ID] = " & WeekIDSQL  
End Sub  

I put the file on a thumb drive and ran it directly from the thumb drive on both laptops, and I still got the error. The same thing happens when the files are opened from their respective hard drives.
I cannot figure out why I get the error on one laptop and not another

Since the code you posted is in the form's OnOpen event, you are saying different behaviors occur only in opening of this form? On working laptop, when the form is opened are you prompted for Weekstartdate and Weekenddate and upon entering form successfully opens? And on non-working laptop, when form is opened, the 3464 error raises with no input prompt? If so, what line is highlighted in VBA?

My first guess would be regional setting affecting date format.  I would start with explicitly convert data types to dates where needed.

@Michal you nailed it. The regional date format had the three letter day abbreviation in it. I changed the regional format to be mm/dd/yy, and it works now. Thanks a lot for the help, and for teaching me something new.

It is probably caused by a Reference marked as MISSING. Check that in the VBE. This can cause Now() to fail.
As a suppplemental test, this should run on both machines:
strSQL = "SELECT tblWeeks.ID FROM tblWeeks WHERE #2024-11-10# Between [Weekstartdate] And [Weekenddate];"  

